# NPM works on Command Line, but not in Jenkins

Tags: angularjs, jenkins, npm

I am having trouble getting Jenkins to use the "npm" command from the "Execute shell" (under the "Build" step).

I am attempting to set up a new Jenkins instance (a copy from a previous one). I just imported the old jobs and am now getting the various services that these jobs depend on (e.g. maven, nodejs, ansible etc.) installed.

I am having trouble getting nodejs and npm, in particular, set up.

When I type the command "npm install" on the command line, I get the following:

```
uws@9.14.0 install /var/lib/jenkins/workspace . . .
. . . 
Binary is fine
added 1282 packages in 36.424s
```

When I then attempt to run the same command using the Jenkins execute shell, I get the following:

```
+ npm install
/tmp/jenkins7750702649955218109.sh: line 2: npm: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Why would this command be accessible to me from the command line but not to Jenkins?

Some things I have checked:

*-The path to "node" and "npm" are both on the path. At least "shortcuts" are on the path (this worked in the previous Jenkins instance).*

*-The node and npm binaries have root:root ownership, but their security settings are (currently) 755 (or -rwxr-xr-x).*

*-I have the nodejs plugin installed. Not sure of how to use it, but its settings match those on the previous Jenkins instance. Both instances use the execute shell (as opposed to any special Jenkins tool) to run the "npm" commands, whilst only the old version worked.*

So, what else should I be checking that I am not? What does Jenkins require to access the "npm" command?

Comment: Can you run PATH command in jenkins executable shell and confirm if npm is present in that ??

Comment: So, here are the results to that test:

+ echo /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin . . . more to come with a later edit.

Comment: Good idea. I am embarassed that I had not considered this test. So, here are the results to that test:

+ echo /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

Which differs from the command line:

/usr/local/src/apache-maven/bin:/usr/local/sbin:
/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin

Checking the contents of /usr/local/bin, I see the "node" executable and a shortcut to the "npm" executable.

Don't see the executables in the version Jenkins yielded, but maybe need to check closer.

Any idea why this discrepancy would exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this below options in Jenkins

**Option 1:**

[image]

**Option 2:**

[image]

Comment: Good stuff!
Option 2 worked for me, but I had to change it slightly by leaving the binary off of the path: "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin"
Option 1 worked for the immediate problem, but I was then faced with "line 3: ng: command not found", so I may need to learn more on how to configure the NodeJS plugin.

Comment: Option2 worked for me. Behind a corporate firewall add npm config commands to set registry and http-proxy as well before the npm install.